# Adding record in a database in vb.net

Tags: database, vb.net

I am very new to VB and I have to add a database to my program but when adding functions to my database in the form, like adding new records it comes up with an error and I have no clue how to fix it.

> Paramater @TxtGender has no default value

Here's the picture :
[image: Error @TxtGender has no default value]

This is the code for adding a new record

```
 Private Sub BtnAddRec_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnAddRec.Click

    Dim PregnantCheck As Boolean
    Dim MedicallyCompCheck As Boolean

    If ChkPregnantRec.Checked Then

        PregnantCheck = True
    Else

        PregnantCheck = False

    End If

    If ChkPregnantRec.Checked Then

        MedicallyCompCheck = True
    Else

        MedicallyCompCheck = False

    End If

    Call connection()

    Dim cmd = New OleDbCommand
    With cmd

        .Connection = cn
        .CommandType = CommandType.Text
        .CommandText = "INSERT INTO [patient details] ([First name],[Surname],[Gender],[Date of birth],[Place of birth],[Phone number],[Street Address],[Suburb],[Health Insurance],[Post code],[Pregnant],[Medically compromised]) VALUES (@TxtFirstnameRec,@TxtSurnameRec,@TxtGenderRec,@TxtDobRec,@TxtPlaceofbirthRec,@TxtPhoneRec,@TxtStreetRec,@TxtSuburb,@TxtPostcodeRec,@TxtHealthinsuranceRec,@ChkPregnantRec,@ChkMedicallycompromisedRec)"

        .Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@TxtFirstnameRec", OleDbType.VarChar, 255, TxtFirstnameRec.Text))
        .Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@TxtSurnameRec", OleDbType.VarChar, 255, TxtSurnameRec.Text))
        .Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@TxtDobRec", OleDbType.Date, 255, dtpDOB.Value.Date))
        .Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@TxtGenderRec", OleDbType.VarChar, 255, TxtGenderRec.Text))
        .Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@TxtPlaceofbirthRec", OleDbType.VarChar, 255, TxtPlaceofbirthRec.Text))
        .Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@TxtStreetRec", OleDbType.VarChar, 255, TxtStreetRec.Text))
        .Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@TxtSuburb", OleDbType.VarChar, 255, TxtSuburbRec.Text))
        .Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@TxtPostcodeRec", OleDbType.VarChar, 255, TxtPostcodeRec.Text))
        .Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@TxtPhoneRec", OleDbType.VarChar, 255, TxtPhoneRec.Text))
        .Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@TxtHealthinsuranceRec", OleDbType.VarChar, 255, TxtHealthinsuranceRec.Text))
        .Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@ChkPregnantRec", OleDbType.Boolean, 255, ChkPregnantRec.Checked))
        .Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@ChkMedicallycompromisedRec", OleDbType.Boolean, 255, ChkMedicallycompromisedRec.Checked))

        .Parameters("@TxtFirstnameRec").Value = TxtFirstnameRec.Text
        .Parameters("@TxtSurnameRec").Value = TxtSurnameRec.Text

        '.Parameters("@TxtDobRec").Value = dtpDOB.Value.ToStr
        .Parameters("@TxtGenderRec").Value = TxtGenderRec.Text
        .Parameters("@TxtPlaceofbirthRec").Value = TxtPlaceofbirthRec.Text
        .Parameters("@TxtStreetRec").Value = TxtStreetRec.Text
        .Parameters("@TxtSuburb").Value = TxtSuburbRec.Text
        .Parameters("@TxtPostcodeRec").Value = TxtPhoneRec.Text
        .Parameters("@TxtPhoneRec").Value = TxtFirstnameRec.Text
        .Parameters("@TxtHealthinsuranceRec").Value = TxtHealthinsuranceRec.Text

        .Parameters("@ChkPregnantRec").Value = ChkPregnantRec.Checked
        .Parameters("@ChkMedicallycompromisedRec").Value = ChkMedicallycompromisedRec.Checked
```

Sorry that I placed a large bit of code, but I don't know what to do. The database is in the bin of the program.

[image: The data types and values in the database]

If anyone can help me with this that would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?747983-RESOLVED-quot-Parameter-has-no-default-value-quot-error

Comment: I don't see anything about Deleting.

Comment: CtznKane525 I had a look at the forum you linked but I am a bit confused as to how to incorporate that in my code, could you please show an example. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry Mary, I didn't notice. Thanks for giving me a heads up

Comment: You need to learn to use breakpoints. Put a breakpoint in your code at the line that sets that parameter value (i.e. the first line with `@TxtGenderRec`), step through  and take especial note of what this is being set to. (i.e. what is the value of `TxtGenderRec.Text`). Note that you are actually setting it twice.

Comment: Nick got it, its fixed now

Answer (score 0):

In OleDb the parameters are positional, i.e. their names are ignored, but they must be added in the same order as they appear in the SQL text.

As `@TxtGenderRec` is at the third position in the SQL text, you must add it after the `@TxtSurnameRec` parameter in place of the `@TxtDobRec` parameter.

Other parameters do not match as well.

Comment: There is still an error @TxtGenderRec has no default value

Comment: I notice you have commented out the `.Parameters("@TxtDobRec").Value = dtpDOB.Value.ToStr` line. If you uncomment that do you get a different error?

Comment: `There is still an error` Can you show some updated code based on following Olivier's advice? You had quite a few out of order and since it's the most likely cause of this, it will help to see what your code looks like now.

Comment: If a column is marked as "Required" in Access or as NOT NULL in SQL, a non-empty value must be supplied. Another thing: You can replace `If ChkPregnantRec.Checked Then
        PregnantCheck = True
    Else
        PregnantCheck = False
    End If` by `PregnantCheck = ChkPregnantRec.Checked`. Also you are using `ChkPregnantRec` to set `MedicallyCompCheck`. Shouldn't you be using `ChkMedicallyCompCheck` instead.